# How to load data in hive with two delimiters

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata, hive-serde

I have sample record with format

`9220216686,2011-05-05 22:48:26,28,C,PRE_HOST10_JINGLE_PP-PREF_WELCOME_PP-PREF_PROMO_PP|M001:6|M487:8|M312:3|M183:3|M093,CD,49,`

I want to load the data into hive based on both `,` and `|` delimiters.  I searched and came up with `MultiDelimitSerDe`. But the problem i facing is some records will have minimum columns in M-starting fields like

`9220216686,2011-05-05 22:48:26,28,C,PRE_HOST10_JINGLE_PP-PREF_WELCOME_PP-PREF_PROMO_PP|M001:6|M487:4,CD,49,`

This record consist only two M-starting fields. I know we can solve this using map-reduce job. But is there any way to load the data into hive with single query effectively?

Comment: Load the records with one delimiter i.e. ','.Since the fields are not fixed after M-starting fields,you can store them in one string field and then use string functions to split it with '|' as delimiter.

Comment: But if i loaded the hive table with`,` delimiter and if i want to access second M-field how can i get that. How can i use split function in hive query

Comment: Look into complex data types in Hive documentation

Comment: Thanks, issue solved